# MongoDB Java Driver: Aggregation using $match with multiple condition

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've been doing some search but haven't been able to find the answer. From [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/), In mongo, if

```
$match: { type: "airfare"}
```

translated as:

```
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("type", "airfare") );
```

in Mongo Java driver, how to translate this one into Mongo java driver?

```
$match : { score : { $gt : 70, $lte : 90 } }
```

---

EDIT

This is what I actually wanted to do:

```
$match : { bookingDateTime: { $gte : fromDate, $lte : toDate } }
```

And this is how implemented in mongodb java driver, with no luck so far:

```
DBObject matchFields2 = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("bookingDateTime", new BasicDBObject("$gte", fromDate.getTime()).append("$lte", toDate.getTime())));
DBObject match2 = new BasicDBObject("$match", matchFields2);
```

`fromDate` is a `Calendar` object so hence the `getTime()` method to convert `Calendar` class to `Date` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Object match = new BasicDBObject("$match", 
   new BasicDBObject("score",
   new BasicDBObject("$gt", 70).append("$lte", 90) ) )
```

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, i tried to do this for querying match by date:

Comment: But it did not work and always return empty values. The code can be seen on the edited section.

Comment: can you cross check that if there are documents matching this query, run the command in your mongo shell. `db.coll.find({ bookingDateTime : {$gte : fromData, $lte : toDate} })`

Comment: yes, it found some documents using the following query: `db.BookingJob.find({ bookingDateTime : {$gte : start, $lte : end} });` where `var start = new Date(2013, 6, 12, -16, 00, 00);` and `var end = new Date(2013,6, 12,7, 59, 59);`

Comment: `DBObject matchFields2 = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("bookingDateTime", new BasicDBObject("$gte", fromDate.getTime()).append("$lte", toDate.getTime())));
DBObject match2 = new BasicDBObject("$match", matchFields2);`

you don't have to use `match2`, use the first variable itself i.e. `db.getCollection('coll').aggregate(matchFields2)`